# Map entries become vectors when piped thru a macro

Tags: clojure

In Clojure, a map entry created within a macro is preserved...

```
(class (eval `(new clojure.lang.MapEntry :a 7)))
;=> clojure.lang.MapEntry
```

...but when piped thru from the outside context collapses to a vector...

```
(class (eval `~(new clojure.lang.MapEntry :a 7)))
;=> clojure.lang.PersistentVector
```

This behavior is defined inside `LispReader.syntaxQuote(Object form)` condition `if(form instanceof IPersistentCollection)`.

Does anyone know if this is intended behavior or something that will be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to understand this behavior you need to dive into construction of Clojure sequences and collections.

In fact, every Clojure map is, underneath, a sequence of vectors. Each `[:key :val]` pair is stored as two elements vector.

Have a proper look, you're asking for class of `MapEntry`, which is just a vector! Instead, Clojure class for maps is `clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap` or `clojure.lang.IPersistentMap`. `MapEntry` is just one element, one part of whole map. And, as I said, because each entry in a Clojure map is really a vector, class of evaluated `MapEntry` is vector, as it should be.

Hope my explanation is understandable.